# css table-cell, contents have unnecessary top margin

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am using table-cell arrangement of div blocks in my code. There is a problem in my code.

Preview of how my html looks is [here](http://jsbin.com/avozik/10/edit#preview)

When I have any content (text or image) in my first panel then the `.inner` div of the second and third panel have a top margin of some 10-15 pixels. Why is that ?

Can any one look and let me know what I am missing.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

add `vertical-align:top;` in `#wrapper > div`

See Demo: http://jsbin.com/avozik/14/edit

Comment: For anyone interested in some vertical-align info, [this](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html) is a nice explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar case, and `vertical-align:top;` solves the issue. However I want to elaborate reason behind this:

https://jsfiddle.net/46tyc48y/1/

Because table cells uses `vertical-align:baseline;` by default, the right cell text will align to the baseline(bottom) of the image, creating the phantom spacing on the top. So we need to explicitly set `vertical-align` to bypass this behavior.

Comment: Strangely enough, your fiddle is not how I thought it would have rendered, it looks like the Google logo is vertically aligned to the top yet I don't see a vertical-align anywhere in the code, am I missing something?

Comment: It might make more sense if I just replace the image with a very big one line text. You will see two cells align to baseline https://jsfiddle.net/46tyc48y/5/