# In a table TD tag width is not aligning properly in HTML?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am implementing the table in one of the html for my application in phonegap and I making alignment in percentage, because it fits for all mobile screens.

I created the table with (width=100% and height=60%), and table contains

- 3 table rows  inside my table.
- and each table row contains 3 table data

I want to make equal alignment width for the  tag.

I already assigned 33% for the td tag, but when I checked in emulator and mobile the the width of the *td* tag not come properly.

Please give me the solution for this.

**HTML code:**

```
<table class="metricTable"  background="media/img/Game background.png">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="metrics">                                
                                <input type="hidden" value="matches"/><input class="card_value" type="hidden" value=""/> <div class="card_content" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF"></div>                              
                        </td>                                                                       
                        <td class="metrics">
                                <input type="hidden" value="runs"/><input class="card_value" type="hidden" value=""/><div class="card_content" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF"></div>                              
                        </td>                                                           
                        <td class="metrics">                                
                                <input type="hidden" value="centuries"/><input class="card_value" type="hidden" value=""/><div class="card_content" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF"></div>                         
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="metrics">                            
                            <input type="hidden" value="fifties"/> <input class="card_value" type="hidden" value=""/><div class="card_content" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF"></div>                      
                        </td>                                                           
                        <td class="metrics">                        
                            <input type="hidden" value="batting_average"/>
                            <input class="card_value" type="hidden" value=""/> <div class="card_content" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF"></div>                    
                        </td>                                                                       
                        <td class="metrics">                        
                            <input type="hidden" value="wickets"/><input class="card_value" type="hidden" value=""/><div class="card_content" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF"></div>                                           
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>                                        
                        <td class="metrics">                        
                            <input type="hidden" value="bowling_average"/>
                            <input class="card_value" type="hidden" value=""/><div class="card_content" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF"></div>                                         
                        </td>                                               
                        <td class="metrics">                            
                            <input type="hidden" value="best_bowling"/><input type="hidden" value=""/>
                            <input class="card_value" type="hidden" value=""/><div class="card_content" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF"></div>                                             
                        </td>                                                   
                        <td class="metrics ">
                        <input type="hidden" value="catches"/><input class="card_value" type="hidden" value=""/><div class="card_content" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF"></div>               
                        </td>
                    </tr>
        </table>
```

**CSS code:**

```
.metricTable {
      width:100%;
      height:60%;    
}
.metricTable tr{
    width:100% !important;
    height:20% !important;
}

.metricTable td {
      width:33% !important;  
} 
.metrics{
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the columns will have the same width, why didn't u use `table-layout: fixed;`?

I guess you're facing the same problem of
[css display table cell requires percentage width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834620/css-display-table-cell-requires-percentage-width/19835024#19835024)